# How to grid inside of a shape on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

I'd like to make a shape with a grid inside of it. O course, fitting a grid exactly into a square is simple. But I'm having a hard time fitting a grid into an irregular shape like an ellipse.

[image]

My first approach, for now, is to make a grid inside the shape, and remove the extra with the eraser. But i'm guessing there is a better way to do this. **How do I quickly and easily fit a grid exactly into a shape and then remove the part outside of the shape?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use clipping mask instead.

Create your shape over your grid. right click > Clipping mask

[image]